# Can my laptop run dual 1080p (Sony Vaio - Nvidia 330M)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, sony-vaio, nvidia-geforce, 1080p

I am looking to buy a monitor to setup dual monitors for my laptop and was wondering if my laptop could handle 2 x 1080p.

I have a [Sony Vaio VPCF116FG](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpcf116fg) which has a [Nvidia GeForce 330M](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_330m_us.html) chip and 1GB dedicated graphics memory. The laptop also has a Intel® Core™ i7-720QM Processor (1.60 GHz with Turbo Boost up to 2.80 GHz) but I don't know if that's relevant(?).

The laptop screen has a native resolution of 1080p (1920 x 1080) so I'll be looking at buying a external monitor with 1080p to connect up using a HDMI cable.

So, the question is, will my laptop be able to handle it's own 1080p screen AND an external 1080p screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way to find out and that's to actually do it.

It works. Good times.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop has an HDMI In/Out Output Connector, which is only designed for the input/output of digital video/audio.

Make sure the monitor can receive HDMI input and it will be able to act as your second monitor.

You'll also need to ensure you have the latest motherboard/video drivers from Sony/Nvidia, which will provide the GUI to manage extending your desktop onto a seconday monitor.

Comment: Yeah, fully understand all that... I want to know if my laptop & graphics chip has the power / capability to run 2x1080p.